# Knockout.js {{each}} not listing items in javascript template

Tags: javascript, templates, dom, knockout.js

I've created a simple app that should iist each item from a model in a list, created using a javascrit template.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tpund74/z6bomga5/)

Html:

```
<div id="tagsList" class="box">
    <div class="box-head">
        <h2 class="left">Tags</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Tag" />
        <button>+ Add</button>
        <div data-bind="template: 'tagsTempl'"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script id="tagsTempl" type="text/html">
    <ul>
        {{each tags}}
            <li class="tagItem">
                <span>${Name}</span>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit</a>
                    <a href="#" class="tag-delete">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    //$("#tagDialog").hide();

    var data = [
        { Id: 1, Name: "Ball Handling" },
        { Id: 2, Name: "Passing" },
        { Id: 3, Name: "Shooting" },
        { Id: 4, Name: "Rebounding" },
        { Id: 5, Name: "Transition" },
        { Id: 6, Name: "Defense" },
        { Id: 7, Name: "Team Offense" },
        { Id: 8, Name: "Team Defense" }
    ];

    var viewModel = {
        tags: ko.observableArray(data),
        tagToAdd: ko.observable(""),
        addTag: function() {
            this.tags.push({ Name: this.tagToAdd() });
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel) 
});
```

Output of list:
{{each tags}}
${Name}
Edit Delete
{{/each}}

The scripts file is accessible through viewing source. I'm not sure where my error is. Any help?

Comment: It looks like you need to [include the jQuery template library](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-6-using-jquerytmpl-an-external-string-based-template-engine), but I'm not sure how actively developed that is anymore, or how well newer versions / its replacement plays with knockout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6bomga5/2/). Now it is working like you want it to: The list of tags is being rendered using the knockout standard method as described in the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

**HTML**

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'tagsTempl', foreach: tags}"></ul>
```

**Template**

```
<script id="tagsTempl" type="text/html">
    <li class="tagItem">
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="tag-delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
     </li>
 </script>
```

Also I connected the viewmodel to the view.
For example:

```
<button data-bind="click: addTag">+ Add</button>
```

You simply forgot most of it. I suggest you follow the interactive [tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) on how to do this.

Comment: I think James Thorpe was correct in that the tutorial I had been folowing was importing jquery.tmpl and just failed to mention it. This is exactly what I was looking for and thanks for the tutorials link!